# Android SQLiteException: no such column when executing raw INSERT

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ExampleIngrd (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO ingredients(_ingredient_id, _ingredient) VALUES (2, ExampleIngrd );`

This is my database create statement and I've done the onUpgrade override correctly with new db version number:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TABLE_INGREDIENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_INGREDIENT_ID + " integer not null, " + COLUMN_INGREDIENT
    + " TEXT);";
```

then I execute db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

This all executes normally but but then when I try to insert into the table with this raw query:

```
public String createIngredient(String ingredientName, int ingredientID) {
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_INGREDIENTS+"("+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_ID+", "
        +MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_INGREDIENT+") VALUES ("
        +ingredientID+", "+ingredientName+");", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Ingredient newIngredient = cursorToIngredient(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newIngredient.getName();
}
```

I get the error no such column exists for whatever value in ingredientName, I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. Is there some mistake in my SQL that I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your literals in SQL in `'single quotes'`, or better yet, use parameters:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_INGREDIENTS+"("+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_ID+", "
    +MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_INGREDIENT+") VALUES (?, ?);",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(ingredientID), ingredientName });
```

Without the quotes the string is taken as an identifier e.g. column name.

Also, while using `rawQuery()` like this technically works, it's confusing. Use `execSQL()` for raw queries that don't return values.

Comment: Thanks I had completely forgotten about single quotes on queries like this. Going to change it to use parameters anyway to make it cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Query string in rawQuery() should not be ; terminated. Check below link.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], android.os.CancellationSignal)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal))

Remove ; from your query string.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Works or fails the same way with or without `;`. The documentation incorrectly states that the query "must not be ; terminated".